# Anonymous types and JsonResult in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Are there any issues with using anonymous types with the Json() method in asp.net mvc?

I recently had an issue where returning an anonymous type from a Linq .First() would not work when returned to the jQuery caller. I created a simply subclass inside my controller and simple assigned values from the query object and that seemed to serialize and work fine.

This worked:

```
public class JsonJob
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
};

var jsonJob = from job in db.Jobs
              where job.Id == jobId
              select new JsonJob
              {
                  Id = job.Id,
                  Title = job.Title,
                  Description = job.Description,
                  DateAdded = job.DateAdded,
                  DateModified = job.DateModified
              };

return Json(jsonJob.First());
```

But this did not:

```
var jsonJob = from job in db.Jobs
              where job.Id == jobId
              select job;

return Json(jsonJob.First());
```

Comment: Describe "would not work" in more detail

Comment: Would not fire the success callback. The controller code is being called successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Your second query does not return an anonymous type. It probably returns an entity type (generated by the `DataContext` code generator from the DBML file), which might have a bunch of things you don't like. Returning an anonymous type shouldn't cause a problem as the `Json` method doesn't care about the type name at all:

```
// anonymous type example:
var jsonJob = from job in db.Jobs
              where job.Id == jobId
              select new {  // Note that no class name is specified here 
                 job.Id,
                 job.Title, 
                 job.Description, 
                 job.DateAdded, 
                 job.DateModified
              };
```

Comment: If I do a 'select new { Id = job.Id, Title = job.Title };' the end result is the same. Using an actual defined type seems to work.

Comment: James: What's the end result?

Comment: Success callback from the page is never called. So something is making $.getJSON freak out.

Comment: James: I'm sure `Json` doesn't care about the type name. I just tested it with a simple anonymous type and it worked as I expected. Changing `select new JsonJob {` to `select new {` should not change anything as far as `Json` method is concerned. The problem is probably somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old one, but I had this problem and this is the first solution in Google; it wasn't related to the anonymous class - it was just because I forgot to return my results with AllowGet, e.g.

```
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
```

Whilst it doesn't throw a C# error, you can easily confirm this with a hander in the Application_Error() function in Global.asax.cs or see the 500 error in Fiddler.

Comment: Worked for me, minus the 'u' in Behavior